# Are grpc services registered via MapGrpcService always transient?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I was wondering whether it is possible to have grpc services I register in my Asp.Net Core startup like

```
private void RegisterServices(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder)
{
    endpointRouteBuilder.MapGrpcService<Service.SessionService>();
}
```

to not be regenerated for every request?

The behaviour I notices as of now is that for every grpc call a new service is spun up again. I would have expected that there is a possibility to keep them alive. The default behaviour makes it quote hard to deal with state within the service. As of now I only see two options:

1. Have the grpc service forward calls to the actual service which the grpc service would receive via a DI framework which actually ties the service to a singleton lifetime.
2. Strictly keep services stateless and deliver stateful parts via DI.

Is there no other way to make the services themselves longlasting?

Answer (score 1):

The service itself you will want to maintain the scope of a request.  Constructor code should be considered request level state setup.  As you point out, the proper way to have a larger scope of state is to use an injected singleton (or otherwise differently scoped).

Comment: Just if some other checking this is curious, I impleted it in this way (take in account that `SomeGrpcService` receives as dependency a `StateService` instance that is singleton


```
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.MapGrpcService<SomeGrpcService>();
```